# Jacoco report is not generate with jmockit argline of surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jmockit, jacoco-maven-plugin

I created a simple spring-boot application to demonstrate the issue after I faced a similar issue in my product code and explained the problem using the Dummy project.
I used testNg for writing unit tests of my spring-boot app and JMockit for the @Capturing feature of test classes. Then I wanted to use Jacoco to generate test coverage reports but after adding the Jacoco plugin reports folder and reports not generating (site/jacoco)
I was able to see below console log

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes             
because bootstrap classpath has been appended
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.263 s -- in     
TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.10:report (report) @ testnginit ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ testnginit ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\project\testnginit\testnginit\target\testnginit-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.jar
```

then I commented below configuration of maven-surefire-plugin

```
 <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/jmockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
```

after running the maven install command below error throws

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.001 s <<<     
FAILURE! -- in TestSuite
[ERROR] com.example.testnginit.AdditionTest.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod[public 
void com.example.testnginit.AdditionTest.testAddition()](0) -- Time elapsed: 6.575 s <<< 
FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
"java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.retransformClasses(java.lang.Class[])" because 
"mockit.internal.startup.Startup.instrumentation" is null

[ERROR] com.example.testnginit.AdditionTest.testAddition -- Time elapsed: 0.004 s <<< 
FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
"java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.retransformClasses(java.lang.Class[])" because 
"mockit.internal.startup.Startup.instrumentation" is null

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   AdditionTest.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod » NullPointer Cannot invoke 
"java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.retransformClasses(java.lang.Class[])" because 
"mockit.internal.startup.Startup.instrumentation" is null
[ERROR]   AdditionTest.testAddition » NullPointer Cannot invoke 
"java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.retransformClasses(java.lang.Class[])" because 
"mockit.internal.startup.Startup.instrumentation" is null
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

After I commented jmockit dependency and ran the maven install command the jacoco coverage report was successfully generated under site/jacoco directory.

[image]

I have tried with multiple jmockit versions to fix this and not worked can you help me sort this out, please?
here is my source repository: https://github.com/manoj1995madushanka/jacoco-fix-with-surefire

My pom file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testnginit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testnginit</name>
    <description>testnginit</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.10</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <testng.version>7.8.0</testng.version>
        <jmockit.version>1.49</jmockit.version>
        <test.includes>**/*Test.java</test.includes>
        <test.excludes>**/*IT*.java</test.excludes>
        <surefire-testng.version>3.2.2</surefire-testng.version>

        <maven.compiler.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.1.2</maven.surefire.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-testng.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/jmockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: First quesiton: Why using JMockit it seemed to be not maintained anymore? Furthermore why using TestNG in relationship with Spring Boot because the default is to use JUnit Jupiter. Furthermore I recommend to upgrade jacoco to most recent version 0.8.11

Comment: BTW: Mixing different version of maven-surefire/surefire-testng which is simply not neccessary.. let surefire do that on it's own..Why using `test.include` and `test.excludes` ? This is handled by maven-surefire-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin ...